# Disable the Sync of Profile pictures from SharePoint My Sites to AD

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, my-site, user-profile-property

I'm looking for a way to stop the sync of Profile Pictures between My Sites and Active Directory. Users are editing their profile photo and thus they are synced back. I have seen the Property "Picture Exchange Sync State" and from what I gather I can set this to '0' for it to stop, but I have to do each user profile and cannot find a way to do it in Powershell.

Is there a better way to achieve what I need to get done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the User Profile Service Application, goto Manage User Properties.  Edit the Picture property.  Remove the mapping to the AD property and save the property.

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like you enable the profile Picture importing from AD. Now if you want to stop the sync You have to follow these steps.

- Login on Central Admin with farm admin account
- go to Application Management > Manage Service Applications > Click on User Profile Services.
- On this Page Click on Manage User Properties > Edit the Picture Property
  [image]
- Click Edit the properties and remove the mapping.
  [image]
- Click
- Now run Full Sync.

Comment: Thanks. On my view I do not see the 'thimbnailPhoto' mapping like in your image above. It doesn't look like there is a mapping for it?

Comment: what you seeing there? could you please share the screenshot?

Comment: This is what I see:
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/pf8AhuZ.png"/>

Comment: what is your sharePoint Configuration? did you try to set "Picture Exchange Sync State" to 0?